# Name of a distribution of subsequent successes of a random event

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, terminology

What I am looking for now is the name of the distribution that describes the situation of exactly $k$ successes **in a row** of random events of probability $p$.

To give an example, if $k = 3$, that would be the chance that you subsequently throw heads 3 times *and then* throw tails. If I'm not mistaken (please correct me if I'm wrong), the probability reads as:

$$ P(k, p) =  p^k (1-p)  $$

It's a pretty simple distribution that I'm sure I've come across in class one day, I'm just wondering for its name.

**Pro question:**

A related distribution is the distribution in which you have $N$ trials, and you're looking for exactly $k$ subsequent successes (obviously $k \leq N$ ) of a random event with probability $p$. So it's much like a binomial distribution but for *subsequent* events. Does this distribution have a name?

Comment: Why do you divide by $(k+1)!$, order matters ?

Comment: Because there are k success-events and 1 fail-event, so $k+1$ events in total. Ah, that is wrong, the $k$ events can be ordered in any way you like. I'll change that.

Comment: So the order only matter for the last one only.

Comment: No, it matters for all $k+1$ drawings. HHHT differs from HTHH. Your formula is still wrong.

Comment: So there are $(k+1)!$ possibilities in total. $k!$ of those are the same as ordering doesn't matter for success, ie. $\frac{k!}{(k+1)!}=\frac{1}{k+1}$, right? But correct me if I'm wrong. As you can see, I need to find the name of this distribution to find out the exact formula. ;-)

Comment: Your reasoning assumes that the tail can appear in any position, which is not true. Among HHHH, HHHT, HHTH, HHTT, HTHH, HTHT, HTTH, HTTT, THHH, THHT, THTH, THTT, TTHH, TTHT, TTTH, TTTT, how many are 3 H followed by T ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16918/discussion-between-yellow-and-yves-daoust).

Comment: The distributions you want are the $Geometric(\theta)$ and $Negative-Binomial(k, \theta)$. $Negative-Binomial(1, \theta) = Geometric(\theta)$